# Filtrar un campo hacer un count en una consulta

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo un problema necesito filtrar mi tabla `incidencias` a la cual le hago 3 `count`, el problema es que el ultimo `count` tengo que aplicarlo 2 veces.

Tengo el campo `responsable_incidencia` que puede ser `0` o `1`; necesito contar cuantos `0` Y `1` hay, aparte de mostrar los otros 2 `count` en una tabla. Tengo lo siguiente, pero solo puedo hacer 1 *where* efectivo a la tabla para filtrarla.

```
 $campos = DB::table('incidencias')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(id_incidencia) as ticket,empresa.nombre, sum(incidencias.estado) as solucionado,count(responsable_incidencia) as responsableC,count(responsable_incidencia) as responsableL'))
                     ->join('empresa','empresa.id_empresa','=','incidencias.id_cliente')
                     ->where('incidencias.responsable_incidencia', '=','1' )
                     ->where('incidencias.responsable_incidencia', '=','0' )

                     ->where('id_cliente', '>', '0' )

                     ->groupBy('empresa.nombre')

                     ->orderBy('ticket', 'DESC')

                     ->get();
```

Comment: No termino de entender. ¿es una opción NO hacer el `where('incidencias.responsable_incidencia', '=','1' )`? La única forma de obtener el `count` para ambos casos (`0 y 1`) es no aplicar esta condición

Comment: Puedes dar un ejemplo de lo que deseas obtener como resultado?

Comment: es mas simple con eloquent, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates